# Change of Variables: Ratio and Product of Two Uniform Distributed Random Variables.

Tags: probability, statistics

Alright, here's a tough one that I can't figure out but I feel I've done quite a bit of work. Whether or not the work is right remains to be seen.

Here is the question:

Let $X_1,X_2$ be independent random variables, with $X_1$ uniform on $(5,8)$ and $X_2$ uniform on $(3,12)$. Find the joint density of $Y=X_1/X_2$ and $Z=X_1\cdot X_2$ on the support of $Y,Z$.

Here is what I did:

Density of $f(X_1,X_2)$ is $5 \leq X_1 \leq 8$ , $3\leq X_2\leq 12$.

$Y = X_1/X_2$ and $Z = X_1\cdot X_2$ so $Z/X_1 = X_2$.

Substitute this is and get $Y = X_1/Z/X_1$ so $X_1 = \sqrt{YZ}$ and if we follow a similar pattern then $X_2 = \sqrt{Z/Y}$.

From here I took the Jacobian and ended up with $1/(2y)$.

Whether or not this is correct, I'm unsure of and this is where things get tricky. I set $5 < \sqrt{YZ} < 8$ and $3 < \sqrt{Z/Y} < 12$. Then squared all sides and tried to use these as the limits so I ended up with: $$\int_{25}^{64}\int_ {9y}^{144y} \frac 1{2y} \operatorname dy\operatorname dz$$

This was wrong according to the problem checker and It gave an absolutely awful answer. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I figured it out and the final answer is as follows 1/(54y).

Comment: At first glance: You said "The density $f(X_1,X_2)$ is... " then just gave the support.  What is the joint density?

Comment: actually, I figured this one out xD I was on the right track I just shouldn't have integrated

Comment: Gonna add a comment here for those that are confused. DO NOT INTEGRATE THIS. Take the Jacobian still, for mine I got 1/(2y) then use the formula for uni random variables to get 1/(b-a) so mine was 1/(8-5) and 1/(12-3) then multiply (1/9)*(1/3)*(1/(2y)) and get 1/(54y). This is the final answer.